# Is the editing tools / kitchen sink missing?

Tags: support, bug

Not sure if that's happening only to me, but I've tried in two different browsers and no editing tool (aka kitchen sink) is appearing.

Is SO pranking just me?

Apologies if *kitchen sink* is not the correct term in English for this tool bar... but it's basically where we have tools like these: http://blogforprofit.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/media_1233089480830.png

I also noticed that the 'human being' verification has been applied for the two entries I tried to submit. Am I really becoming a non human and SO is trying to tell me so?

I searched for related topics here in meta as well as in meta.stackoverflow... and no lucky. Any guess?

Cheers

Comment: Do you see the first bar with bold/italics? That's all there is.

Comment: Better an image than words... http://s16.postimage.org/yn8669mgl/PMSE.jpg

Comment: There's a slightly chance that my company has changed some security network policy, restricting content...

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?  Are you able to see any images if you hit this link:  http://cdn.sstatic.net/betameta/Img/wmd-buttons.png

Comment: Does this also happen on other SE sites you may be a member of, or just here on PMSE?

Comment: @jmort253, nops, I can't see any of these icons... and I also checked on StackOverflow and the same happens.

Comment: And http://cdn.sstatic.net/betameta/Img/wmd-buttons.png?t=8098 ?  If you can see this one, then it's most likely something with your browser cache. If not, then we have made the community management team aware that there may be a problem with the CDN.

Comment: @TiagoCardoso Let's gather some information. Try the things [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100103/155160) and let us know what turns up?

Comment: Images for the same action in SO, using Chrome and IE. Notice I rarely use IE, so it's highly unlikely to be something 'cached' in IE...
http://postimage.org/image/hg10h86s3/
http://postimage.org/image/eager0o5v/

Comment: Actually, apologies... I can see the images on both links. In a glance, I had understood if i was able to see those icons *when editing a post*.

Comment: @AnnaLear, trying now... partial results: although http://status.netdna.com/ sounds to be ok (all green but a blue - maintenance - down below), tracing route to sstatic.stackexchange.netdna-cdn.com is timing out.
_
Tracing route to sstatic.stackexchange.netdna-cdn.com [67.201.31.70]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Comment: I tend to believe that's because of all firewalls our network is under, so I believe the best here is to test when I'm home. In case I face the same there, will let you guys know. Otherwise, it's highly possible that I'll have to get used to some restrictions when @ office.

Comment: @TiagoCardoso Sounds good. Keep us posted.

Comment: Either way, many thanks for your promptly assistance guys!

Comment: Hi folks, I'm going to remove this question tmw... just tested @ home and everything is fine, therefore I can only assume that it's something related to our network security structure. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @TiagoCardoso The wmd.js file that powers that editor may be getting blocked by your company's proxy/firewall. Do you know what network security systems are in place? We can try to get our stuff whitelisted.

Comment: Hi @AnnaLear, due to the 'market' my company is operating on, the restrictions are as higher as possible... so I'm just getting used to use the formatting commands manually. Thanks!